# Responsive Image and careousel issue CSS

Tags: css

i am not css designer but now i have to make our image carousel responsive for our web site using css. i do it first in js fiddle and it is working. working jsfiddle url as follows http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/hx9jy3ne/5/

but the moment i use the same css for our live site then notice no responsive when screen width or height change. i just copy this code and css

```
<style type="text/css">
.myImgs {
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
.headerCarouselwrapperOuter {
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
  background-color:#000000;
}
</style>

<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPHeader" role="banner" id="main_header_big2" style="width:100%">
    <div class="headerCarouselwrapperOuter" style="width:100%">
        <div class="headerCarouselwrapper">

<!--    <img src="http://www.bba-reman.com/NewSiteImages/new-bba-header-image1.jpg" />-->
            <img src="../images/new-bba-header-image1dyna.jpg" class="myImgs" />
            <img src="../images/new-bba-header-image2dyna.jpg"  class="myImgs" />
            <img src="../images/new-bba-header-image3dyna.jpg"  class="myImgs" />
            <img src="../images/new-bba-header-image4dyna.jpg"  class="myImgs" />
            <img src="../images/new-bba-header-image5dyna.jpg"  class="myImgs" />
            <img src="../images/new-bba-header-image6dyna.jpg"  class="myImgs" />
<!--      <img src="http://www.bba-reman.com/NewSiteImages/new-bba-header-image2.jpg" />
    <img src="http://www.bba-reman.com/NewSiteImages/new-bba-header-image3.jpg" />
    <img src="http://www.bba-reman.com/NewSiteImages/new-bba-header-image4.jpg" /> -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

my live site url is **www.bba-reman.com**

anyone can mind to see my live site and suggest me what i am missing in my code. thanks

Comment: Your website is not responsive and you use several fixed width and etc.

Comment: The first rule in 'langarth.grid.css' says `body{min-width:960px; overflow:hidden;}` Guess what minimum width your site will have...

Comment: it would be enough help if some one guide me how to make my site's image carousel responsive. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You've forgotten to include the viewport meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

NB: The `initial-scale` just means that no zooming will applied when the site is initially loaded.

Comment: if i add the viewport meta tag then my code will be working ? i have doubt. would u mind to see my live site html strcuture because i guess i have to add more css to handle this issue..........what u think. thanks

Comment: I quickly checked your site but didn't go into depth on whether it was "setup" to be responsive or not, I just noticed you're missing the viewport meta tag, which is the classic one that gets forgotten. It's not a magic wand that makes your site responsive for you automatically but without it, even if your code is setup to be responsive, mobile devices won't display accordingly.

Comment: i add your suggested meta tag but output was same.........image was not responsive inside carousel.

Comment: just see my jsfiddle code which was responsive after adding some css to div and image tag........i did the same to our live web site but the trick does not work for our live web site........definitely i am missing something. would mind to help me. thanks

Comment: It doesn't look like your site is fluid or that it's using any media queries for different viewports... Take a look at this great post for an intro on responsive design: [http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-responsive-web-design](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-responsive-web-design)

Comment: i do not want to make my whole web site pages responsive. i am just after my image carousel. it would be enough help if some one guide me how to make my site's  image carousel responsive. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Two things..

1) The images in your carousel need to be responsive, which is possible using the following css (I didn't see it in your fiddle, but I did see it on your live site):

```
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
```

2) As others are saying, your website is not responsive.  So that means there is not going to be any "quick fix" for making just the carousel responsive.  The carousel is nested within other elements that have fixed widths.  If the elements that contain the image carousel cannot become smaller, neither can the carousel itself (since being "responsive" means scaling to the size of the parent container).  Two issues I see right away are, as someone else mentioned, the `min-width: 960px` on the `body` element.  Another issue is the fixed width that is applied to the actual carousel wrapper element: `.headerCarouselwrapper: width: 1280px;`

The reason the carousel is working in the fiddle is because it is not wrapped in any elements that are set to a specific width.

Comment: so tell me what i need to change in html and css? should i set width of headerCarouselwrapper to 100% instead of 1280px?

Comment: what is about this code `max-width: 100%;
height: auto;`   where to add this code?